# Automate a script changing a word R

Tags: r, automation

I have a script for creating a graph that shows some networks. I have list of words and I need to create a graph for each of these words (more than 50). There must be of course a way of automatizing this ...

I just need to replace the word in the beginning of the script.

I have a list of words:

```
words <- c('hello', 'sun', 'weather', 'goodbye')
```

and I want to run a script multiple times (the same number that my list hast) changing only one word every time. Like this:

```
Term <- "hello"

# execute the rest of the script (That throws a plot)

# then execute the same script but for

Term <- "sun"
```

Comment: So basically you are looking for a loop? Depending on the exact task look for `for`-loop or `apply`-functions.

Answer (score 2):

A basic approach is a simple `for`-loop.

```r
words <- c("hello", "sun", "weather", ..., "goodbye")

for (word in words) {
  Term <- word
  [do stuff]
}
```